# How to list all registries npm would use?

Tags: npm

I have a package in a private registry. I know it is there as I can pull it into some projects, but I can't pull it into one. I have the correct `.npmrc` one directory up but am still getting a `404 error`.

Is there a way to check all registries that `npm` would use on install?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can show the registry of a specific package with the `npm view` command.

```
> npm view angular

angular@1.7.5 | MIT | deps: none | versions: 136
HTML enhanced for web apps
http://angularjs.org

keywords: angular, framework, browser, client-side

dist
.tarball: https://registry.npmjs.org/angular/-/angular-1.7.5.tgz
.shasum: d1c1c01c6f5dc835638f3f9aa51012857bdac49e
.integrity: sha512-760183yxtGzni740IBTieNuWLtPNAoMqvmC0Z62UoU0I3nqk+VJuO3JbQAXOyvo3Oy/ZsdNQwrSTh/B0OQZjNw==
.unpackedSize: 2.1 MB

maintainers:
- angular <devops+npm@angular.io>
- angularcore <angular-core+npm@google.com>
- petebd <pete@bacondarwin.com>

dist-tags:
latest: 1.7.5         old: 1.2.32           previous_1_4: 1.4.14  previous_1_5: 1.5.11

published 4 weeks ago by petebd <pete@bacondarwin.com>
```

When you use `npm config get registry` you will see the default registry.

```
> npm config get registry

https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

With `npm config list` you can see custom configurations. When you have registered a registry for different scopes you will see them here

```
@polymer:registry=<url register A>
```

Comment: I know this is old, but where does the registry under .tarball come from? I am trying to install a a project in a docker container and some dependencies cannot be found since  the tarball value is used as registry location instead of the npm config registry entry.